# PuttyFatalError- networkerror:connection timed out

Tags: putty, vmware-player

I am unable to connect vmware player through putty. My vmware ipadd and ipaddr from http://www.whatismyip.com/ is different. I get connection timed out error. Please can some one help me the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. From your post I understand that you have VMware Player installed on the same host you're running PuTTY on.

The IP address you see on websites is an external IP, i.e. the address of your local network on the Internet. If you have a router, then it's the router's IP. If not, then it's an IP of your computer.

What VirtualBox does by default is it works like a router (see [Wikipedia article for NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)). Therefore, it creates a separate local network managed by your computer. All virtual machines are connected to that router and have their own local IPs assigned - IPs that aren't accessible from the Internet. You can check machine's IP by running `ipconfig` (on Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux).

In PuTTY you have to enter the local IP of the virtual machine. Also make sure that SSH/Telnet server is running on that machine, otherwise it simply won't work because there's nothing for PuTTY to connect to.